# Base a column on another lookup column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, list, 2016, lookup-column

I have a list with a lookup column (Reviewers). In my view, I want to have two columns (Assigned To and Review Complete) that are checkboxes. In the first (Assigned To), the manager selects all the users from the Reviewers lookup that are assigned to that file. In the second column (Review Complete), I want to have only those reviewers selected in the Assigned To column display and then they can check off their name when they have completed the review task for that item. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By design, your needs cannot be realized. Because the Lookup column does not support getting value from another Lookup column.

**Lookup Supported Column Type**

- Single line of text
- Number
- Date and Time

**Lookup Unsupported Column Type**

- Multiple lines of text
- Currency
- Person or Group
- Calculated
- Hyperlink or Picture
- Custom Columns
- Yes/No
- Choice
- Lookup